# Multiple values to same key in a Groovy Map

Tags: list, dictionary, groovy, collections

I am new to both coding and Groovy. I have a requirement to populate a data map values based on the values in a list but with a matching criterion. For e.g. say the 2nd character of the list value is equal to 2, then map it to "Number2" key in the data map. Likewise, I may end up having multiple list values matching this criterion. I am struggling with the below code - it works but it is always picking up the last occurrence of matching value in the list. What I understand is you can only have one unique key-value pair in the map. But is there any other way of achieving this? Sorry, I'm a total rookie here. All the help is appreciated. Thank you!

```
def map = [:]
def ent = ['123','133','124','143','125']

ent.each{
    println it.charAt(1)
}

ent.each{
    if(it.charAt(1) == '2'){
        println it.charAt(1)
        println "is in entity $it"
        map['Number2'] = it
        map.each{ k, v -> println "${k}:${v}" }
    }
}
```

Expected Result:

```
['Number2':[123,124,125],'Number3':[133],'Number4':[143]]
```

Comment: So are you saying that that index 0 in your current list, which is character 123, should create a key/value pair of Number123 = 123? And index 1 which has a value of 133 should create a map entry of Number133 = 133?  How do you want to handle duplicate keys?  If that isn’t what you want I’m going to need you to re explain what you want. Preferably give me a list with values and then show me what the resulting map should look like. I can definitely help you here. Because if you always map 2 to key Number2 then duplicates shouldn’t matter.

Comment: Are you looking for suggestions on how to create unique keys for duplicate values?  If so I can create a multi map structure for you

Comment: Hi Chris, no. Not what I meant. In the ent list in my code there are 3 values that have "2" in the 2nd place - i think index(1). So any value in list ent that has 2 in 2nd position irrespective of the length of the value should get mapped to "Number2". Hope this clarifies.

Comment: I think what you mentioned in your second comment is exactly what I need. Unique keys to duplicate values. I would welcome your multi map structure..

Comment: Yea it clarifies. And you want to essentially have a key:value pair where the key ( in this case Number2 ) does not need to be unique?  Do you need the data structure to have the same O(n) searching sorting as a map or not?  Because if so that’s impossible, if not I can make a multimap datastruxture or write something that imports Apache gauava with grape

Comment: Yes, i want the key to be unique and multiple unique values map to a key. Not necessarily need sorting on the map.. 

so the result should look something like this for the map:
['Number2':[123,124,125],'Number3':[133],'Number4':[143]]

Comment: Ok I see now. I’ll modify your code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm probably getting the wrong end of the stick, but do you mean:

```
def ent = ['123','133','124','143','125']

def map = ent.groupBy { "Number${it.charAt(1)}" }
```

#### Edit, with a pre-filter step

```
def ent = ['123','133','124','143','125']

def map = ent.findAll { it.charAt(1) in ['2', '3'] }
             .groupBy { "Number${it.charAt(1)}" }
```

Comment: Hi Tim - this is great. I can live with this. But if there is a way to restrict the groupby that would be great. For e.g. if the 2nd character is either 2 or 3 then add it to the map, else ignore it. Possible?

Comment: You'd need to add a pre-filter step...  It can't be done as part of the groupBy.  You _could_ do a post-filter, but that would be more work for the computer...  Added the filter step to the answer above